Find the analytic function $f(z)$ if $v(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$
I try to solve this in the polar form, then by taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$ and $r$ from the question I obtain
$v_r = -\frac{1}{r^2}(\cos \theta - \sin\theta)$
$v_\theta = \frac{1}{r}(-\sin\theta - \cos \theta)$
Then using the C-R equation : $u_r = \frac{1}{r}v_\theta$
and integrate it with respect to $r$, i can get the $u(r,\theta)$
and then I taking the derivative of $u$ with repsect to $\theta$ and I get
$u_\theta =\frac{1}{r}(\cos \theta -\sin \theta)+f'(\theta)$
using the C-R equation : $v_r = -\frac{1}{r}u_\theta$
I get the $f'(\theta)=0$ and so that $f(\theta)$ = $C$
However why in the solution, the $C$ is not included in the analytic function?

Because it translates the angle, making a rotation.
It's easier to identify the function of $z= x+i \ y$ directly
$$\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\frac{1}{2} ((x+i\ y)+(x-i\ y))-\frac{(x+i\ y)-(x-i\ y)}{2 i}}{(x+i \ y) (x-i \ y)}=\frac{(1-i) z^*+(1+i) z}{2 z z^*}=\Re\left(\frac{1-i}{z}\right)=\Re\left(\frac{1-i}{x+i\ y}\right)$$
